# using sed to capture groups

Tags: sed, bioinformatics

I have a file that looks like that:

```
chr1    3143567 3143568 .3-2704 1.000000|ENSMUSG00000102693.2
chr1    3143599 3143600 .3-2705 1.000000|ENSMUSG00000102693.2
chr1    3143631 3143632 .3-2706 1.000000|ENSMUSG00000102693.2
chr1    3143663 3143664 .3-2707 1.000000|ENSMUSG00000102693.2
chr1    3143695 3143696 .3-2708 1.000000|ENSMUSG00000102693.2
chr1    3143727 3143728 .3-2709 1.000000|ENSMUSG00000102693.2
```

I'm writing 2 sed expressions to filter everything before the `|` first and with result file I discard everything after the `.` like so:

`sed -n -e 's/^.*|//p' original_file.txt > first_result.txt`

`sed -n -e 's/\..*//p' first_result.txt > final_result.txt`

How can I write all of that in one line ?

The end goal is to capture `ENSMUSG00000102693`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your commands would discard lines containing no `|` character, and lines where the mouse gene identifier has no version number.  I'm not certain this is intended, but it's a side effect of using `sed -n` with the `p` flag on the `s` command.  I'm going to assume that this is unintended.

Just use two expressions with `sed`:

```bsh
sed -e 's/.*|//' -e 's/\..*//' file >newfile
```

With a `grep` command that has the non-standard `-o` option, and assuming that you just want to extract all Ensembl mouse gene stable IDs from the file (and that the file only contains stable IDs that you'd like to extract),

```bsh
grep -o 'ENSMUSG[[:digit:]]*' file >newfile
```

You may also use two chained `cut` commands, each one doing similar modifications of the data as the two `sed` substitutions earlier in this answer. Using static cut would probably be quicker than using a regular expression, but I doubt you'd see any major speed differences unless your input data is huge.

```bsh
cut -d '|' -f 2 file | cut -d '.' -f 1 >newfile
```

Comment: you seem to know the data well, working in bioinformatics ? yes i just want the gene stable ID without version number and `|` since I need to use these IDs to find the human orthologs genes

Comment: @moth If you're using the Ensembl Perl API, you might just as well do this parsing operation from Perl instead of as a separate external step. The orthologs would then be fetchable with the Ensembl Compara Perl API, I presume. You may want to ask for the specifics on the [bioinformatics SE site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You could use a single `sed` expression as below. Match everything up to the last `|` to ignore and then capture the part before the last `.` and exclude it in the result. On any sed with POSIX BRE support

```bsh
sed 's/.*|\([^.]*\)\..*/\1/'
```

If Awk is preferred,

```bsh
awk -F'[|.]' '{ print $(NF-1) }'
```

Comment: It seems better to use `\([^.]\+\)`. The `.*` will capture too much and have to backtrack. You want to capture all non-dot characters up to the dot; just say that. Also, there is no reason to backslash-escape the dot inside the character class.

Answer (score 4):

You can use GNU `grep` (wich seems to have a slightly better performance than `sed`):

```bsh
$ grep -Po '(?<=\|)[^|.]+' first_result.txt 
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
```

- The pattern `(?<=\|)[^|.]+` means "look for all the characters that are not a `|` or a `.` (`[^|.]+`) starting at (and excluding) the initial `|` (`(?<=\|)`)".

With `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed 's/.*|\([^|]\+\)\..*/\1/' first_result.txt  
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
ENSMUSG00000102693
```

- The pattern `.*|\([^|]\+\)\..*` means "remove all the characters between `|` and `.` (`.*|`, `\..*`) and capture what is in between (`\([^|]\+\)`), finally replace all by the captured pattern (`/\1/`).

Or more succintly:

```bsh
$ sed -E 's/.*\|([^|]+)\..*/\1/'
```